# How to split string provided as user enter in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, input, split

How to split a `type` of `car` and `color` that user provides as input.

Input format is:

```
<Type>#<Color>
```

Output will show how many type of car that has the same `color`

input example:

```
how many cars : 10
sedan#red
truck#yellow
van#white
suv#black
sedan#black
roadster#red
suv#gray
coupe#gray
minivan#white
truck#red
```

**output** has to be sort in alphabetical

```
black 2
gray 2
red 3
white 2
yellow 1
```

Tried a sample code, still not done, but where kinda struggle about how to split the array `T^T`

**Class1**:

```
 public class Class1 {

    private String type ;
    private String color;
    private String format;

    public Class1() {
        this.type = "";
        this.color = "";
        this.format = "";
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getFormat() {
        return format;
    }

    public void setFormat(String format) {
        this.format = format;
    }

    public void split () {  
        String part[] = format.split("#");
        setType(part[0]);
        setColor(part[1]); // i don't know if this will work or not.. 
    } 
}
```

**Class2**:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Class2 {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int n ;
        String format ;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        Class1 [] dataArray = new Class1[n] ;
        Class1 data = new Class1();

        for(int a = 0 ; a <= dataArray.length ; a++) {
            dataArray[a] = data;
            data.setFormat(br.readLine());

            data.split();
            data.getType();
            data.getColor();
        }
    }
}
```

Coding is still not completed and still don't know how to split the array. Please help me solve this!

Comment: if your input is strictly `type#color` then, for case simply check for `str.indexOf("#color")` and count++ for same color.

Comment: Have you tried running this snippet? Did it produce the wrong result?

Comment: Side note: if you rename Class1 to Car and Class2 to CarColorCounter, your code will be a bit easier to understand. The rest already looks great, though.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `for` loop from this:

```
   for(int a = 0 ; a <= dataArray.length ; a++) {
        dataArray[a] = data;
        data.setFormat(br.readLine());

        data.split();
        data.getType();
        data.getColor();
    }
```

to this:

```
    for(int a = 0 ; a < dataArray.length ; a++) {
        Class1 data = new Class1();
        dataArray[a] = data;
        data.setFormat(br.readLine());

        data.split();
        data.getType();
        data.getColor();
    }
```

The two important changes are:

1. You should only loop while `a < dataArray.length`, otherwise
   you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when `a == dataArray.length`.
2. You need to create a new instance of `Class1` each time you read in
       a new line, and store in position `a` of your `dataArray`

Other than this it looks fine. Obviously there are some quibbles in your design - maybe `setFormat` should call `split`, rather than requiring a separate call? - but you should now be able to iterate over `dataArray` and count colours, probably using a `Map<String, Integer>`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the new object `Class1 data = new Class1();` inside the for-loop, rather than outside of it as otherwise it will be overridden every time the loop runs.

Also iterate through `a < dataArray.length` instead of  `a <= dataArray.length`.

I have added the `groupingBy` to get the count grouped by the  the color name. Then I sorted the `entrySet` of the resulting `Map<String, Integer>` and printed out the contents.

I have achieved the expected output without modifying your code too much.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        int numberOfCars;
        String format ;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        numberOfCars = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        Class1 [] dataArray = new Class1[numberOfCars] ;

        for(int a = 0 ; a < dataArray.length ; a++) {
            //Initializing new instance everytime
            Class1 data = new Class1();
            data.setFormat(br.readLine());
            data.split();
            dataArray[a] = data;
        }
        //Creating a Stream of Class1 objects
        Arrays.stream(dataArray)
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(car -> car.getColor(), Collectors.counting()))
              .entrySet() //Getting entries from Map
              .stream() //sorting after the Map is created to preserve the sorted order
              .sorted(Comparator.comparing(entry -> entry.getKey())) //Sorting by key, that is the Color property of Class1
              .forEach((entry) -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " "+ entry.getValue()));
        }catch (NumberFormatException | IOException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
              System.out.println("Error occurred try again");
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```